# Crash on __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort

Tags: ios, runtime

I don't see what my problem is. My application has a lot of crashes in the background during the maintenance process
I appreciate any idea or thought that might help me investigate this issue.

````
config-sync-scheduler-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1584 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1c1c mach_msg + 76
2  CoreFoundation                 0x7698 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3  CoreFoundation                 0xb98c __CFRunLoopRun + 1212
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1f3c8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5  Foundation                     0x18d54 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6  Foundation                     0x19510 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
7  eWallet-iOS                    0xdd2854 __31-[XXXXXXX start]_block_invoke + 958056
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1c04 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x3950 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
10 libdispatch.dylib              0xb0ac _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 664
11 libdispatch.dylib              0xbc10 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 392
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x16318 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 656
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x11b0 _pthread_wqthread + 288
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xf50 start_wqthread + 8```


I didn't find any other information
````

Comment: Did you find the root cause?